# Faster For loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have this piece of code, where i'm looping through 250,000 items.
Here are the steps within the code:
1. subset data for a given product
2. merge (left) the data with month dataframe.
3. Replace the null product names with that particular product name
4. Replace NA values for sales with 0

Here is a sample data set for two products.
Data:

```
data2 <- data.frame(product_no = c("A", "A", "A", "B","B","B"), 
                           sales = c(200, 130, 221, 310,109, 98), month = c(1, 4, 5, 8,1, 12), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

month_unique <- as.data.frame(seq(1,12, by=1))
colnames(month_unique)[colnames(month_unique)=="seq(1, 12, by = 1)"] <- "month"
```

Code:

```
unique_product <- unique(data2$product_no)
data3 <- data.frame()

process_time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:length(unique_product)){
  step1 <- subset(data2, product_no==unique_product[i])
  step2 <- merge(month_unique,step1, by="month", all.x = TRUE)
  step2$product_no <- unique_product[i]
  step2[is.na(step2)] <- 0
  data3 <- rbind(data3, step2)
}
Sys.time() - process_time
```

Expected Result:

```
data3
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: First, you change your column name from `productId` to `product_no` (should it just be `product_no` in your reproducible version?) Second, is all you're trying to do make sure that there are 0 values for months that don't appear in `data2`? (Is there ever extra data in `month_unique`?

Comment: Yea sorry. I've edited to product_no. Should ran through now. It should only be product_no in the reproducible version. Actually yes, all i'm trying to do is make sure there are zero values for months where there is zero value in data2. There is no extra data in month_unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `expand.grid` to create all combinations of month and `product_no`, then replace the NAs with 0.

```
library(tidyr)

combinations <- expand.grid(month = 1:12,
                            product_no = unique(data2$product_no),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

result <- merge(combinations, data2, all.x = TRUE)
result <- replace_na(result, list(sales = 0))
```

Note that I'm using the `replace_na` function from the tidyr package, but you could also just do

```
result$sales[is.na(result$sales)] <- 0
```

You can also use the `left_join` function in dplyr, which is often faster than `merge`. In dplyr functions are often (though not necessarily) chained together with `%>%`:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- combinations %>%
    left_join(data2) %>%
    replace_na(list(sales = 0))
```

Comment: Took just a minute. Can you recommend other packages I should look into to avoid using for loops? Thanks.

Comment: @user3116753 Absolutely; the [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) package, especially `group_by` (for cases where you want to split the data and recombine). While you didn't need it here, note that dplyr has a function `left_join` that is often faster than merge; you should try it. I'll edit in the code.

Comment: @user3116753 `data.table` is also great for this and often faster, though the syntax is a bit less intuitive to begin with.

Comment: @user3116753 Note also that if you have all months present at least once (in some product) in your data, then tidyr's `expand` is designed for this purpose: `data2 %>% expand(product_no, month) %>% left_join(data2) %>% replace_na(list(sales = 0))`

Comment: Solid! Thank you Akhil and Mr. Robinson.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I was curious, and because you said you had so many products to iterate through, I ran this with the for loop, using lapply, using David's code, and then running it in parallel (on 4 cores).  Here's what I came up with:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> library(parallel)
> 
> data2 <- data.frame(productId = c("A", "A", "A", "B","B","B"), 
+                     sales = c(200, 130, 221, 310,109, 98), 
+                     month = c(1, 4, 5, 8,1, 12), 
+                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> data2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:1000, function(i) data2))
> data2$productId <- rep(1:2000, each = 3)
> 
> month_unique <- as.data.frame(seq(1,12, by=1))
> colnames(month_unique)[colnames(month_unique)=="seq(1, 12, by = 1)"] <- "month"
> 
> 
> #* For running the original code
> unique_product <- unique(data2$productId)
> data3 <- data.frame()
> 
> 
> system.time({
+   for (i in 1:length(unique_product)){
+     step1 <- subset(data2, productId==unique_product[i])
+     step2 <- merge(month_unique,step1, by="month", all.x = TRUE)
+     step2$productId <- unique_product[i]
+     step2[is.na(step2)] <- 0
+     data3 <- rbind(data3, step2)
+   }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   4.79    0.01    4.81 
> 
> 
> #* Function that is equivalent to the for loop
> dataFn <- function(up, data2, month_unique){
+   step1 <- subset(data2, productId==up)
+   step2 <- merge(month_unique,step1, by="month", all.x = TRUE)
+   step2$product_no <- up
+   step2[is.na(step2)] <- 0
+   step2
+ }
> 
> system.time({
+   data3 <- do.call("rbind", 
+                    lapply(unique_product, dataFn, data2, month_unique))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
    2.1     0.0     2.1 
>   
> #David's code
> system.time({
+   combinations <- expand.grid(month = 1:12,
+                               productId = unique(data2$productId),
+                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
+   result <- left_join(combinations, data2, 
+                       by = c("month" = "month",
+                              "productId" = "productId"))
+   result <- replace_na(result, list(sales = 0))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> 
> # run in parallel
> system.time({
+   cl <- makeCluster(4)
+     clusterExport(cl, "dataFn")
+     clusterExport(cl, "data2")
+     clusterExport(cl, "month_unique")
+     data3_parallel <- 
+       do.call("rbind",
+             parLapply(cl, unique_product, dataFn, data2, month_unique))
+     stopCluster(cl)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.27    0.03    1.99 
>
```

So using an apply function appears to increase the speed; there doesn't appear to be a benefit to parallelization (perhaps the size of the task is too small?), and David's code is lightning fast.

Comment: Nifty stuff. Thank you Benjamin.